# Finding annotated packages in Java?

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

What is the cleanest way to find all packages annotated with a particular package-level annotation in their `package-info.java`?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something like the [reflections](http://code.google.com/p/reflections/) library to do the bulk of your classpath scanning work; others are available in libraries like Spring/etc.

Comment: thanks for your answer @Dave . I am trying to find a comparison of Reflections vs Spring, could you give me a pointer or tell me your opinion about which one is better for finding packages and/or classes with certain annotations, without knowing the names of such packages/classes in advance?

Comment: @Sergio I'd use reflections or similar purpose-built, standalone library, unless I was already using a larger framework that happened to have the same functionality as part of its normal infrastructure. IMO start with reflections and see if it meets your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/packages.html

> Typically package-info.java contains only a package declaration,
>   preceded immediately by the annotations on the package.